# interval function in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Query:

```
SELECT INTERVAL '300' month,
       INTERVAL '54-2' year to month,
       INTERVAL ' 11:12:10.1234567' hour to second 
  FROM DUAL;
```

The output of the above query is:

```
+25-00,+54-02,+00 11:12:10.1234567
```

Can someone please explain to me how this query is giving this output, with an explanation about the interval function?

Comment: See: http://askanantha.blogspot.com/2007/08/interval-datatypes-in-oracle.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`INTERVAL` is not a function it's a keyword that introduces an interval *literal* and such denotes a *data type*. Similar to what the literals `DATE '2011-05-04'` or `TIMESTAMP '2011-05-04 17:18:19'` are doing.

Details about interval *literals*
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions009.htm#SQLRF52084

Details about the interval *datatype*:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#i128552

Answer (score 9):

Interval is a function which is used to deduct or add (days,years,months,hour,minutes and seconds) to the given date.
interval '300' month : 25-0
Reason : 300/12(months) gives you quotient as 25 and remainder as 0 so the output will be 25-0

interval '54-2' year to month : 54-2
Reason : As you have not mentioned any date it is giving as it is.
if you use 
select sysdate + interval '54-2' year to month from dual;
output will be : 1-12-2066

sydate : 1-10-2012
so adding 54 to 12 = 66
and adding 2 months to oct which will be dec.

Same with the last option as well.