# How does Interval keyword work in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 queries :

```
SELECT 300*interval '1' HOUR FROM DUAL  --   0 5:0:0.0 (Output)

SELECT 300* interval '1' minute FROM DUAL -- 12 12:0:0.0(Output)
```

I am unable to get how is the interval Keyword working and what is the format of the Output produced ?

Comment: I believe you have mixed your "(Output)" results in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the best to always know all of your participants of multiplication or any other math operation to undesrstand it.

**'1' HOUR**

```
select interval '1' HOUR from dual;
```

will return 1 hour, then you multiple it with number 300 and you will get:

```
+000000012 12:00:00.000000000
```

Because (300 * 1) / 24 = 12.5. or 12 days and 12 hours.

**'1' minute**

The same thing happend with minutes where your result is 5 hours. This query :

```
select interval '1' minute FROM DUAL
```

will return 1 minute and then you multiple it with number 300 to get this:

```
+000000000 05:00:00.000000000
```

Because (300 * 1) / 60 = 5 or 5 hours.
[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=48a25a1e9c2066fac4316f1503363ed6)

**P.S.**

Depending on the tool you use you can see this results as:

+12 12:00:00.000000

+00 05:00:00.000000

Comment: Sir , I couldn't get this +000000012 12:00:00.000000000                                                           Please share the documentation link for the output format ,I am unable to get the meaning of this output

Comment: Hi @radha, I wil lbe more than happy to help you more...please tell me what do you get ? In your question you said you do not understand how this works and you wrote your result is `12 12:0:0.0(Output)` ?

Comment: Hi @radha what do you mean when you say "Please share the documentation link for the output format" ? Every step of the select statement is explained in my answer. Please try to elaborate more specific what is your problem.

Comment: I couldn't understand the meaning of leading zeroes in +000000012 12:00:00.000000000 and how to interpret 12:00:00.000000000  ,is it 12hrs ,0 minutes ,0 seconds ?

Comment: It is 12 days and 12 hours

Comment: Actually I wanted to get the documentation for Interval keyword so as to get the meaning of Output format

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-dates-timestamps-and-intervals#interval

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879448/interval-function-in-oracle

Answer (score 1):

Your first query :

```
--300 * 1 hour => 12 days 12 hours which is +000000012 12:00:00.000000000
SELECT 300 * ( INTERVAL '1' HOUR ) FROM DUAL; 

-- 300 * 1 minute => 300 Minute which is 300 / 60 = 5 Hours =>  +000000000 05:00:00.000000000
SELECT 300 * (interval '1' minute) FROM DUAL
```

Hope it helps